# Are array keys implicitly coerced to numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, coercion

I'm in the book, *This & Object Prototypes, Chapter 3: Objects.*

In the arrays section, the author says if you add a property to an array, but the array looks like a number, it will end up as part of the array index:

```
myArray["3"] = "baz";
console.log(myArray.length);
console.log(myArray[3]);
```

It looks like JavaScript is implicitly coercing the "3" string into the number 3, then it's saying place "baz" in index 3 of the array.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it's the other way around. All keys in JavaScript objects *are strings*, and arrays are objects. That means `myArray[3]` is the same as `myArray["3"]` *because all keys, if not already strings, are coerced into strings because all JavaScript object keys are strings*. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects):

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string.

And:

> Please note that all keys in the square bracket notation are converted to String type, since objects in JavaScript can only have String type as key type. For example, in the above code, when the key `obj` is added to the `myObj`, JavaScript will call the `obj.toString()` method, and use this result string as the new key.

For example:

```
const obj = {
  toString() {
    return 'foobar';
  }
};

const anotherObj = {};
anotherObj[obj] = 'baz';
//anotherObj.foobar is now 'baz'
```

Since `obj` is converted to a string implicitly, `obj.toString` is called which returns `'foobar'`, which is used as the key value. The same applies for arrays -- when using bracket notation. All keys are strings, and accessing using bracket notation coerces the expression in the brackets into a string.

Comment: I presume the `hint` for the `ToPrimitive` coercion of the object is `String` ?

Comment: @Taurus In the context of this answer, I don't think `ToPrimitive` is even performed. All keys are converted to strings before being set on the object.

Comment: So, just a plain `toString` call ? Wouldn't the operation be the same if a `ToPrimitive` with a string `hint` was to occur ? How did you come to this conclusion ? No aggression meant.

Comment: @Taurus `ToString` abstract operation I believe. Can't verify right now.

Comment: But before a `ToString` call can be made, an object must undergo a `ToPrimitive` call.

Comment: @Taurus Can you show me where in the spec it says that? Objects can be directly converted to strings via ToString IIRC.

Comment: Here are the specs for [`ToPrimitive`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive). I believe that `ToPrimitive` is used with `string` for the `hint` parameter. I am very certain that it is `ToPrimitive` because if you modify the object's `ToString`,  `valueOf` will be tried, if that one doesn't return a primitve, a `TypeError` will be thrown. Same thing that happens during `ToPrimitive`. I believe that `toString` is rarely directly called under the hood, I also believe that `ToPrimitive` is used whenever an object needs to be represented in primitive form.

Comment: Did you find anything inconsistent ?

Comment: @Taurus [The spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-type) says: *"An integer index is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see 7.1.16) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integer ≤ 2^53-1. An array index is an integer index whose numeric value i is in the range +0 ≤ i < 2^32-1."*

Comment: In [7.1.16](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-canonicalnumericindexstring): it says *"The abstract operation CanonicalNumericIndexString returns argument converted to a numeric value if it is a String representation of a Number that would be produced by ToString"* - My guess is that index collections must have numbers produced by ToString that can be converted back to a number. Not clear though.

Comment: Other than that, all the spec mentions is *"Properties are identified using key values. A property key value is either an ECMAScript String value or a Symbol value. All String and Symbol values, including the empty string, are valid as property keys. A property name is a property key that is a String value."*

Comment: Thanks! It would be odd if something other than `ToPrimitive(string)` is used, its most likely that, though.

Comment: So javascript converts an integer to a string every time I access an element in an array?? That seems awfully inefficient